# How to record sound in Android app

Tags: android, audio, audio-recording

I'm developing an Android application, a part of this app is a simple xylophone, what i must do is  the implementation of a function, that records the  xylophone sounds  when the user press a button.

When a user press a button, like do, re mi, etc  the sounds is played using a mp3 saved in raw folder...

1) Is it possible do this ?
2) Can someone explain how i can "capture" the sound and record it in sd card?
3) Is it possible implements  "record" "play" "stop" "reproduce" function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without root, Android can't record internally (or say 'digitally') what is coming out of the speaker or the headphones. The reason might be copyright issues, so that it is not possible to produce digital copies of what is played back over the Android device.

Of course, you can record it with the internal microphone(s) if the signal is loud enough, but the loss of quality is significant. Additionally, you have background noise and the tapping noise of the finger tips of the user on your xylophone.

The best solution would be that you mix the samples corresponding to the keys programmatically and send the result to the speaker and at the same time into a sound file. Complicated, but optimal.

Answer (score 3):

> You can record audio by using this code:

```
private void startRecording() {
        mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

        try {
            mRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
        }

        mRecorder.start();
    }
```

> I am searching for how to record audio with **earphone**, not from
>   **speakers** please share link in the comment If anyone have Idea about it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,you can capture and store audio in sd and later play it . Check out these links .

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_audio_capture.htm

Comment: The only problem of this solution is that the recording is done using the microphone ! What that i need is record the sound WITHOUT microphone because i want play the only xylophone sounds

Comment: I dont get u. 
If u want the default xylophone sounds, you can download it from internet.

Comment: In case you want to store the entire sequence, u can merge the corresponding mp3 files.

Comment: I have created Android application that allows you to play the xylophone, when a user presses the button corresponding to the note you play a sound, (I downloaded and inserted into my project with the sounds of mp3). What I want to do now is to give the user the possibility to record the music that he played.

Comment: I am not sure how u can record the music that is getting played. Try if you can merge several mp3 files(the xylophone tones) with proper delays to get the full music.

Answer (score -1):

```
MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
recorder.setOutputFile(PATH_NAME);
recorder.prepare();
recorder.start(); // Recording is now started
...
recorder.stop();
recorder.reset(); // You can reuse the object by going back to setAudioSource() step
recorder.release(); // Now the object cannot be reused
```